# How to Update Ranking on jQuery UI Sortable Table Rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/g5pc5z4f/) and let me know how I can Re number (order) the sortable table when the rows are sorted using jQuery UI sortable?

As you can see I have

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Elem 1</th>
            <th>Elem 2</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
            <td>X</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
            <td>X</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
            <td>X</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
            <td>X</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
            <td>X</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

and

```
$( "tbody" ).sortable();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an [update](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) event occurs, You can select the last `<td>`'s and update their text using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method by returning the index of it's parent `tr` relative to all `<tr>` elements using [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method as follows:

```js
$("tbody").sortable({
  update: function(e, ui) {
    $("tr td:nth-child(3)").text(function() {
      return $(this).parent().index("tr");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom: 1pt solid grey;
  background: khaki;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Elem 1</th>
      <th>Elem 2</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="border_bottom">
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border_bottom">
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border_bottom">
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border_bottom">
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border_bottom">
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks T J, This is perfect!